# PdfSharp: drawing one PdfPage onto another PdfPage

Tags: pdfsharp

I'm currently reloading the PdfPage as a XPdfForm in order to use it as a graphics source. I'd like a way to either convert a PdfPage into and XImage, so that I can then draw it on another XGraphics, or some way to draw PdfPage directly onto an XGraphics.

Note: The point of asking how to get an XPdfForm from a PdfPage is so I can avoid reloading the file in anyway from a stream. I don't want to go through the save/load cycle.

Comment: What do you mean with "I'm currently reloading the PdfPage as a XPdfForm in order to use it as a graphics source"? Do you create the PdfPage with PDFsharp or do you load it from a file? You are reloading it but don't want to reload from a stream? How are you reloading? Maybe switching to a different reload will do the trick.

Comment: PdfSharp.Drawing.XPdfForm.FromStream(stm); is what I'm currently using. I'd like to create an XPdfForm from a PdfPage, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can load pages from PDF files using XImage.FromFile. Append the page number with the # sign, e.g. "test.pdf#17" to get page 17.

See also:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_a_form_XObject_a_page_from_an_external_PDF_file_27

Comment: I'm trying to do it without reloading the PDF from a stream.